# Clean up dependancies after Destroy AND scheduel

Tags: terraform

One can (or should) also target a module and not the whole infrastructure while using destroy Something like this.

```
terraform destroy -target=module.<module_name>
```

or better see what you are going to destroy first

```
terraform plan -destroy -target=module.<module_name>
```

I agree with above comment.

1. how do I schedule to destroy after certain condition?
2. How do I destroy (or reflect changes to) other dependent modules?

Comment: Where does that comment come from? I'd strongly suggest that targeting resources or modules is _not_ what you want to do in day to day operations and only if you have some particular, transient edge case to handle and know what you're doing. Instead you should be structuring your Terraform resources so that creating and destroying should be doable on whole directories as default instead.

Comment: terraform is the infrastructure as code, you need write the wrapper script to schedule some custom jobs.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand. The comments, on which my question was based, are in this forum. I forgot the name but the name starts from K.